# Nova compute and network is unable to contact nova service after restart manage services

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, openstack, postgresql-9.0, openstack-nova

I have 2 node setup for openstack.

1st node contains manage service like `nova-api`, `nova-scheduler`, 'glance` ...
2nd node contains network and compute services.

When I check `nova-manage service list` all service are showing up.

When I restart the manage node (node 1) compute is disconnected.

When compute try to connect manage node its shows error in compute log.

```
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nova/manager.py", line 155, in periodic_tasks
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager     task(self, context)
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2244, in _heal_instance_info_cache
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager     context, self.host)
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nova/db/api.py", line 594, in instance_get_all_by_host
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager     return IMPL.instance_get_all_by_host(context, host)
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/api.py", line 103, in wrapper
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/api.py", line 1582, in instance_get_all_by_host
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager     return _instance_get_all_query(context).filter_by(host=host).all()
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1922, in all
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager     return list(self)
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2032, in __iter__
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager     return self._execute_and_instances(context)
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2047, in _execute_and_instances
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager     result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1399, in execute
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager     params)
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1532, in _execute_clauseelement
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager     compiled_sql, distilled_params
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1640, in _execute_context
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager     context)
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1633, in _execute_context
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager     context)
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 330, in do_execute
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2013-01-21 20:49:28 TRACE nova.manager OperationalError: (OperationalError) socket not open
```

When I restart the compute and network service it solve the problem. But until i restart the compute or network its gives error.

When I check on compute for the socket open for controler.

```
[root@compute ~]# ps -ef | grep compute
nova     30859     1 27 18:51 ?        00:00:03 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/nova-compute --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf --logfile /var/log/nova/compute.log
root     30996 30807  0 18:51 pts/0    00:00:00 grep compute

[root@compute ~]# netstat -p | grep 30859
tcp        0      0 compute:56988        controller:postgres     ESTABLISHED 30859/python
tcp        0      0 compute:37869        controller:amqps        ESTABLISHED 30859/python
tcp        0      0 compute:37871        controller:amqps        ESTABLISHED 30859/python
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3588759 30859/python
```

There are 2 socket open for controller. `postgres` and `amqps`.
When I run `reboot now` on controller and check how many socket available for controller.

```
[root@compute ~]# netstat -p | grep 30859
tcp      208      0 compute:56988        controller:postgres     CLOSE_WAIT  30859/python
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3590103 30859/python
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3588759 30859/python
```

In this `postgres` socket is close.

When all service come up in controller. I run the same command to check the socket connected to controller. I got same result.

Why compute not create new socket for `postgres`?

Comment: check nova.conf for your sql server configs.  but it looks like your sql server may not be up and operating properly.  I'd start there.

Comment: sql server is up and running. When I check `nova-manage service list` its shows all services in :-) status. Only compute and networks are in XXX status. When I check log for compute I got this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket error that you're getting is from nova-compute attempting to contact the database you have configured in nova.conf, as Matt Joyce pointed out above. Earlier in the log, you can see all the values that the service is configured with. Look for the string "Full set of FLAGS" - that will at least hint towards what was configured in there - it hides the actual value of "sql_connection" from the log output (since it typically has a password embedded in it), but it might help to explain what's happening there.

From what I'm reading of your question, the nova-compute log files shows this error *until* your restart the service. Do I read correctly that it works after that?

Assuming that's correct, is there something that is configuring nova after the base packaged are installed? A run of chef, puppet or the like thats adding configuration details after the service might have started up with an incorrect configuration?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was checking the problem. I got some hints on that. The problem is when services are running it create socket for `amqp` and `postgres`. When controller services down both socket close from compute side. When services come up on controller side compute try to connect it. It create socket for `amqp` but unable to create socket for `postgres` and due to that it gives `socket not open` error.

Comment: The error is still the same - the nova-compute service isn't able to open a socket connection to your database when it started. I haven't deployed with Postgres previously, but I'd suspect the postgres driver you're using and the nova-compute service don't work together to automatically attempt to reconnect on an initial failure.

Comment: Will you please inform how to check driver version ? I am using Essax Nova Copute and PostgreSQL 9.0.